# Are the card backs identical for Once Upon a Time 2nd and 3rd editions?

Tags: edition-comparison, once-upon-a-time

I was just about to order Once Upon a Time with the extra blank cards pack, when I found out that a third edition of the game had just been released.

Are the card backs the same, so I can mix third-edition Once Upon a Time with the second-edition blank cards pack? I can't seem to find a third-edition blank cards pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer your question directly, but I'm going to guess they're different, based on the redesign information. However, it may not matter. This looks like [the 3rd edition blanks pack](http://www.atlas-games.com/product_tables/AG1031.php) you're looking for. The release date is October 2012, the same as the [3rd edition release](http://www.atlas-games.com/product_tables/AG1030.php).

Comment: Neat, I missed that product!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe they are the same.  I ordered the 2nd edition expansion along with the third edition base game, and they did not have the same card backs.